# Can java method annotation get the parameters of the method and pass a new parameter to the method?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to have ParameterParser, which helps process the method parameters and class variables, and then put the processed parameters into a ParameterWrapper for the method.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ParameterParser {
     // get the method's and its parent class's parameters
}

public class anyclass {
    @ParameterParser
    public void anymethod() {
        // get a ParameterWrapper from @ParameterParser
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible to use java method annotation, since I can't find examples about annotation to access the parameters of method and class. And I can't find examples of annotation pass parameters to the method, either.